# jQuery CuteTime Plugin and Ajax Data - False conversion in IE + Safari?

Tags: jquery, plugins, time

I have a site with a [liveticker](http://www.gute-mathe-fragen.de/liveticker) which loads new forum events and adds them to an HTML table.

For the time field I am ajax-loading the datetime of each event (e.g. `2013-02-15 17:28:03`), and converting them via [jquery plugin cutetime](http://tpgblog.com/cutetime/) to human readable format, e.g. `22 minutes ago`.

Problem with CuteTime is that the [recent version](https://github.com/theproductguy/CuteTime) (from 2010) has some issues in dealing with dynamically loaded AJAX data.

My **current solution** seems to work a bit:

1.At first the ajax call loads the entire forum events as html table, then I assign the cutetime plugin:

```
// initial load at page startup
$('#responsecontainer').load('./liveticker', {ajax:1}, function() {
    // convert datetime to readable date format
    $('.timestamp').cuteTime();
});
```

2.Then I check every 30 seconds for new events, and assign cuteTime each time on the loaded data:

```
$('#responseEvents').load('./liveticker', {ajax:lastevent}, function() {
    // stuff...
    // convert datetime to readable date format
    $('.timestamp').cuteTime();
})
```

This seems to work in Firefox and Chrome. However, in Internet Explorer 9 all `$(.timestamp)` elements get the same text assigned: `just now`.

Does anyone know a solution to this bug / problem?

--

Note: On the cutetime-site I found a [comment](http://tpgblog.com/cutetime/#comment-3594) about ajax. Somebody there stated his workaround:

> I had to hack my app to make additional fields so i first copy all
>   the values into all my spans, then call cuteTime.

But I am not sure if this is in any way connected to the Internet Explorer Bug I am facing now...

Comment: By the way, if anyone knows another plugin that can handle conversions into "human readable date formats" and is ajax-ready I would be happy to hear your recommendations.

Comment: I read the datetimes through `console.log($('.timestamp').text());` both match in Internet Explorer and Firefox before conversion. Just after conversion with line `$('.timestamp').cuteTime();` the IE version is setting the same string on each event item.

Comment: Note: Meanwhile, I disabled the conversion if a visitor uses IE by `!($.browser.msie)`. Would be glad if anyone can help me still...

Comment: Just figured out that there is the same problem in Safari!

Answer (score 1):

It was not the AJAX call. Indeed, I used the normal datetime format (from mysql) and tried to convert that format with cutetime.

Reading the site of the developer, I stumbled over this sentence:

> timestamp MUST be a valid Date().parse 'able' format

as well as:

> If neither cutetime attribute nor valid object text exist, then the timestamp is assumed to be ‘now’.

Bingo! Now I am formattting the datetime to ISO8601 date format server site with:

`$timeCode = date("c", strtotime( $row['datetime'] ));`

and I get dates in this format: `2013-02-17T15:26:21+01:00` which work for js-conversion in all browsers!